# My ajax is simple, but doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve some data from weather api in form loading. I am also new in ajax, and i don't know ajax work in form loading.Here is my code.
Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
        type:"GET"
        , url:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"
        , dataType:"json"
        , success: function(data){

            $('#result').text(data)

        }   
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Look in a Browser-Console like in Firefox/Chrome hitting F12.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) format because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of browsers.
Also note that having an implementation of the `error` callback helps in debugging....If you use Chrome, [ctrl+shift+J](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) is you friend...(note that for jsonp type of calls the error callback is not fired, but it did fire with your original code, aka json as dataType)

```
  $.ajax({
        type:"GET"
        , url:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"
        , dataType:"jsonp"
        , success: function(data){
            $('#result').text(data.name);
        } 
       , error: function(e) {
           alert(e);
       }
    });
```

working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8p4U/5/)

Comment: Great! your advice is work. If you are ok, i would ask you why you use dataType:"jsonp"? why not use "json"? Thanks again

Comment: See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) and several other questions and answers here on SO

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be

```
$('#result').text(data + "OKkkkkk");
```

And I dont think that through the `cross domain` AJAX will communicate and also you are getting JSON data ,so you need to filter that data and can display.

As per your need ,you need an error block like

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    , url:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"
    , dataType:"json"
    , success: function(data){

        $('#result').text("data" + "OKkkkkk")

    },
    error : function(){
        alert('Ajax call was failed');
    }   
});
```

If the ajax call is success then it will goto success block and input the result data into result div or if it is fails then it will alerts on going to the error block

Comment: Hi Gautam3164, how could i know my ajax request is success or not? I just want to know does my ajax work. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have placed data in double quotes, so it is interpreted as text. The correct form is:

$('#result').text(data)